# Deck shuffling algorithm isnt "human" enough

Tags: python, sorting, random, shuffle

For fun I made this deck shuffling function to mimic how people imperfectly shuffle a deck. They cut it nearly in half and use the "ruffle" method to interweave the left and right decks together and then they repeat the process any number of times. The deck is never perfectly weaved together. You might shuffle them like L1, L2, R1, L3, R2, L4, R3, etc. or R1, L1, R2, R3, L2, etc. . The problem in my code is that successive reshuffles never switch the first and last cards of the deck. If in the first shuffle the bias says put L1 at the top of the deck, then every reshuffle will also have L1 at the top. I moved `bias = random.random()` into the while loop so it should reset every time and therefore sometimes change the order. Is this some weird instance of pseudo random and recursive code not playing well together?

```
def shuffle_human(cards,reshuffle):
    split = random.randint(-1*int(len(cards)/20),int(len(cards)/20)) #creates a bias to imperfectly split deck +- 5% of the deck size
    L = cards[:int(len(cards)/2)+split] # creates left deck
    R = cards[int(len(cards)/2)+split:] # creates right deck
    D =[]                               # empty new deck
    while len(D)< len(cards):           
        bias = random.random()          # creates a bias to "incorrectly" choose 
          if L and bias <=.5:           #     which deck the next card will come from**strong text**
            l = L.pop(0)                # pops the card from the deck and appends it in. 
            print(l)                    # formatted this way so i can see whats going on 
            D.append(l)     
        if R and bias >.5:           # same thing for right deck
            r = R.pop(0)
            print(r)
            D.append(r)
    print(D)
    if reshuffle>0:                     # see if there are any reshuffles attempts needed 
        shuffle_perfect(D,reshuffle-1)  # recursive call to reshuffle the deck. 

shuffle_human(deck,3)
```

Problematic output

```
 [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4]   # initial shuffle
 [0, 1, 5, 9, 6, 10, 7, 2, 8, 3, 4]   # reshuffle 1
 [0, 10, 1, 7, 5, 2, 9, 8, 6, 3, 4]   # 2
 [0, 2, 10, 9, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 4]   # 3
```

As you can see it always has L1 and Ln-1 or R1 and Rn-1 as the first and last digits of the output deck, depending on the result of the first shuffle. No matter how many reshuffles I do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but you aren't calling `shuffle_human` recursively; you're calling some other function `shuffle_perfect`. Don't use recursion for simple iteration, though.

Comment: Your indentation is off.  I assume this compiles, so you didn't copy right, or you're mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: might need to delete this whole post.... I also made a perfect shuffling algorithm and didnt realize i was calling it there. It works now.

Comment: I don't believe that the code you've exhibited is the code that generated those 4 lines of output. Firstly, there are print() statements in the code that aren't reflected in the output, and secondly there are discrepancies in naming. This is understandable if you're chopping and changing the code a lot to try to narrow down the problem, but it makes it impossible to be confident that the problem you're trying to hunt down is something that's actually present in the version of the code that you're showing us.

Comment: @chepner if you post your comment as an answer i'll give you the credit.

Comment: I consider that a typo.

Comment: With a bunch of mathematics you can prove that by numbering the cards with random n-bit numbers (allowing duplicates), and sorting by that number, you can simulate n riffle shuffles.  It's those duplicate values that emulate the imperfection of a human shuffle, and extending n to more bits makes that less likely to matter, just like doing more riffles.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't run your code properly because you used a function named 'shuffle_perfect' but your code seems to work just fine. the first and last element switches once in a while. but for a better investigation see the histogram of each element of the list in a 1000 iteration and look at the std of the histogram for example. In that situation, you can make a clearer judgment about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First I modified and added to your code to make the recursion work:

```
from random import random, randint


def shuffle_human(cards, reshuffles=0):
    # creates a bias to imperfectly split deck +- 5% of the deck size
    split = randint(-1*int(len(cards)/20), int(len(cards)/20))
    L = cards[:int(len(cards)/2)+split]  # creates left deck
    R = cards[int(len(cards)/2)+split:]  # creates right deck
    D = []                               # empty new deck
    while len(D) < len(cards):
        bias = random()          # creates a bias to "incorrectly" choose
        if L and bias <= .5:  # which deck the next card will come from
            # pops the card from the deck and appends it in.
            l = L.pop(0)
            # formatted this way so i can see whats going on
            D.append(l)
        if R and bias > .5:           # same thing for right deck
            r = R.pop(0)
            D.append(r)
    # print(D)
    if reshuffles > 0:  # see if there are any reshuffles attempts needed
        # recursive call to reshuffle the deck.
        return shuffle_human(D, reshuffles-1)
    return D


if __name__ == '__main__':
    yes = 0
    no = 0
    deck = list(range(10))
    for i in range(100000):
        res = shuffle_human(deck, 3)
        print(f'shuffle_human({deck}, 3):', res)
        if res[0] == deck[0] and res[-1] == deck[-1]:
            yes += 1
        else:
            no += 1

    total = yes + no
    print('\nunmixed:')
    print(f'yes: {yes/total*100:.2f}%')
    print(f'no: {no/total*100:.2f}%')
```

Running this it repeats the shuffle multiple times and does a tally, it seems to show that your function works fine. Maybe the issue is caused by your `shuffle_perfect` function in which case we can't help you because you haven't shared it.

FYI: it seems to keep the first and last element about 2% of the time when using a reshuffle count of 3